# How to load data programmatically from shapefile into feature class (geodatabase)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, data, esri-geodatabase

Can some Genuis here help me programmatically (using python and comtypes) load shapefile data in to an existing geodatabase (feature class). The attributes of the shapefile has to match with the feature class fields. For instance i have field "Height" in shapefile which has to go into "Height" field in the feature dataset.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good reason to use ArcObjects, why not just use the [Append](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000050000000) tool in arcpy?

Comment: Another option would be to use a `InsertCursor`.

Comment: How did i miss the Append tool. I will check it out and see whether it can fulfill my task. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specify the word, "load". In other words, each shapefile as its own Feature Class, or multiple shapefiles into one feature class?